# Nginx exporter not found Ingress nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, prometheus, nginx-ingress, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm trying to post metrics from my nginx-ingress to prometheus. I've read kubernetes.io readme files for deployment and configuration. My nginx is running without fails, but node exporter is failing after a retry.

I have two containers in mentioned pod as a side cars, configured as below in my environment.

Why does nginx exporter keep failing?

My nginx-ingress.yaml file is shown below:

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "9113"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress
      containers:
      - image: nginx/nginx-ingress:edge
        name: nginx-ingress
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
        - name: stub
          containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        args:
          - -nginx-configmaps=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-config
          - -default-server-tls-secret=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-server-secret
          - -enable-prometheus-metrics
         #- -v=3 # Enables extensive logging. Useful for trooublshooting.
         #- -report-ingress-status
         #- -external-service=nginx-ingress
         #- -enable-leader-election
      - image: nginx/nginx-prometheus-exporter:0.4.2
        name: nginx-prometheus-exporter
        ports:
        - name: prometheus
          containerPort: 9113
        args:
          - -web.listen-address
          - :9113
          - -nginx.scrape-uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/stub_status
          - -nginx.retries=5
          - -nginx.retry-interval=1
```

Prometheus-cfg.yaml down below:

```
- job_name: 'ingress-nginx-endpoints'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod
    namespaces:
      names:
      - nginx-ingress
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
    action: replace
    target_label: __scheme__
    regex: (https?)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    action: replace
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    regex: (.+)
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    action: replace
    target_label: __address__
    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
    replacement: $1:$2
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    regex: prometheus-server
    action: drop
```

Comment: can you please check if you see this error in promtheus logs? `level=error ts=2019-10-24T08:40:29.69463515Z caller=main.go:218 component=k8s_client_runtime err="github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:307: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:ingress-nginx:prometheus-server\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"nginx-ingress\""
`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add an exporter to nginx-ingress, please read the documentation about the annotations you added.

Those annotations activate the exporter directly on the ingress exporter, with your configuration you open the port 9113 2 times, remove the prometheus exporter container and it should work.

Comment: I tried it, but there is no metric on prometheus. I set 9113 port on nginx then on args added like; 
args:
          - -nginx-configmaps=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-config
          - -default-server-tls-secret=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-server-secret
          - -health-status=true
          - -enable-prometheus-metrics

Comment: Did you try to check the output of the pod on port 9113? Let's check if the default exporter is in error or the prometheus conf :)

Comment: updated question with prometheus related config file.

Comment: Could you try a port forward on the port 9113 on your pod to check if you have the output for prom?

Comment: I did but nothing changed. Also i restarted prometheus server

Comment: "ports": [
 {"name": "http","hostPort": 80,"containerPort": 80,
            "protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "name": "https",
            "hostPort": 444,
            "containerPort": 443,
            "protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "name": "stub",
            "hostPort": 8080,
            "containerPort": 8080,
            "protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "name": "prometheus",
            "hostPort": 9113,
            "containerPort": 9113,
            "protocol": "TCP"
          }
        ]